# Почему нельзя вставлять картинки в предвыборную речь?

Tags: дефект, поддержка, выборы

Вообще не понимаю, как наличие картинок связано со спамом, да ещё и в предвыборной речи. Что, когда спам-бот выдвигается в модераторы, он обязательно постит картинку??

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Котиков хотели запостить?

Comment: Правильно, что не дают, надо капчу ещё обязательную ввести :) P.S. но раз уж тут есть текстовое описание, то это не "баг", а "так-задумано". И если уж хочется картинок, надо писать "предложение".

Comment: Капча там есть. Я когда публиковал свой спич, меня система спросила "а вы не робот?", им наверное преференции положены.